# Difference between getCurrentPositionAsync and watchPositionAsync and why doesn't anything show up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-location

I'm trying to get the position of the user and have it constantly updating and showing on the screen. I simply can't figure out why this isn't working :(

Here's my code:

```
import { Alert, Linking, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import * as Location from "expo-location";

export default function DateFinder() {
  const [hasForegroundPermissions, setHasForegroundPermissions] =
    useState(null);
  const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState(null);
  const [textPosition, setTextPosition] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const AccessLocation = async () => {
      function appSettings() {
        console.warn("Open settigs pressed");
        if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
          Linking.openURL("app-settings:");
        } else RNAndroidOpenSettings.appDetailsSettings();
      }

      const appSettingsALert = () => {
        Alert.alert(
          "Allow Wassupp to Use your Location",
          "Open your app settings to allow Wassupp to access your current position. Without it, you won't be able to use the love compass",
          [
            {
              text: "Cancel",
              onPress: () => console.warn("Cancel pressed"),
            },
            { text: "Open settings", onPress: appSettings },
          ]
        );
      };

      const foregroundPermissions =
        await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (
        foregroundPermissions.canAskAgain == false ||
        foregroundPermissions.status == "denied"
      ) {
        appSettingsALert();
      }
      setHasForegroundPermissions(foregroundPermissions.status === "granted");
      if (hasForegroundPermissions == true) {
        console.warn("bob");
        const location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest },
          (location) => {
            setUserLocation(location);
            setTextPosition(JSON.stringify(location));
          }
        );

        console.warn("bob");
      }
    };

    AccessLocation().catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{textPosition}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
      backgroundColor: COLORS.background_Pale,
      flex: 1,
      // justifyContent: "flex-start",
      //alignItems: "center",
    },
    image: {
      flex: 1,
      // height: null,
      // width: null,
      //alignItems: "center",
    },
    scrollView: {
      backgroundColor: COLORS.background_Pale,
    },
  });
}
```

Sadly, it seems that nothing happens but I don't know why. Nothing shows up in the text and the watchPositionAsync doesn't update. Maybe I need to do something for the screen to update since useEffect only runs everytime the screen is updated but i can't seem to figure out what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state `hasForegroundPermissions` needs some time to update, so your `if(hasForegroundPermissions == true)` condition executes before the state update with previous value which in not `true`. So it won't execute the code inside the if condition. So change your code like below to get that condition to work

```
...
      if (foregroundPermissions.status === "granted") {
        setHasForegroundPermissions(true);
        console.warn("bob");
        const location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Highest },
          (location) => {
            setUserLocation(location);
            setTextPosition(JSON.stringify(location));
          }
        );
        console.warn("location",location);
      }
      else setHasForegroundPermissions(false);
...
```

Comment: Boss you are a life saver! Is it normal that the code doesn't keep on giving me the position? Shouldn't it keep updating as I move around? If not, how should I modify my code so that it does. I thought it was different from getcurrentposition because it kept on giving us updates as the app is in the foreground.

Comment: Try passing `distanceInterval` or `timeInterval` if android to option like mentioned here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationoptions
or try the answer posted by Nora here.

Comment: Thank you so much man you saved me, I dont know why but the default distanceInterval didn't seem to work even if I ran 20 meters outside. Passing a distanceInterval fixed my issue. I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the unfortunate experience of having to deal with Expo location... there's no technical explanation to my answer, it's simply a bug that everyone seems to be willing to ignore.

Setting any accuracy, interval, distance, or deferment seems to halt the whole watcher from ever working. Unless you **only** use `accuracy` and `activityType` and set them to `BestForNavigation` and `Fitness`, e.g.:

```
const location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
    {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        activityType: Location.ActivityType.Fitness
    },
    (location) => {
        setUserLocation(location);
        setTextPosition(JSON.stringify(location));
    }
);
```

I have personally had a better experience using `startLocationUpdatesAsync` with tasks:

```
TaskManager.defineTask("recorder", ({ data, error }) => {
    if(error)
        return console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    
    if(data) {
        const { locations } = data;

        // trigger a call to your component here
    }
});

// ...

Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync("recorder", {
    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
    activityType: Location.ActivityType.Fitness
});
```